# Is possible to make URIResolver.resolver() be called more than once? I need to add multiple documentFragments

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I need to make a XSLT transformation using multiple sources to result an one XML file.

For example: I have a XML Message to transform, a XSL file to make the transform, and a document fragment imported by XSL file.

If i use only one documentFragment it works. Following this link:

- [how-to-merge-2-xml-streams-in-java-by-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730231/how-to-merge-2-xml-streams-in-java-by-xslt)

...the `StringURIResolver` works great. But it works only for one document fragment injection (Using only ONE `document()` function on XSL as the link's example). Following the link's code as example I made some changes on it to support multiples injections:

```
public final class StringURIResolver implements URIResolver {

Map<String, String> documents = new HashMap<String, String>();

public StringURIResolver put(final String href, final String document) {
    documents.put(href, document);
    return this;
}

public StringURIResolver put(HashMap<String, String> parameterMap) {

    // Make a set from Map.
    Set<Entry<String, String>> mapSet = parameterMap.entrySet();

    // Get the Map Iterator
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> i = mapSet.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> mappedValue = (Map.Entry<String, String>) i.next();
        documents.put(mappedValue.getKey().toString(), mappedValue.getValue().toString());
    }
    return this;
}

public Source resolve(final String href, final String base) throws TransformerException     {
    System.out.println("RESOLVE WAS CALLED");
    final String s = documents.get(href);
    if (s != null) {
        return new StreamSource(new StringReader(s));
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

My problem here is simple, the `StringResolver.resolve()` method is called just ONE time for my entire XSL file.

The snippet of my XSL looks-like:

```
<xsl:variable name="Test.reply" select="document('Test.reply')" />
<xsl:variable name="Test.reply2" select="document('Test.reply2')" />
<xsl:variable name="Test.reply3" select="document('Test.reply3')" />
```

In my JUnit test, when the transform occurs, only one time the resolve is called, the message "RESOLVE WAS CALLED" is printed ONCE, and the second and third fragments are not used.

I'm using a Saxon9 Transformer using the following code:

```
private static TransformerFactory getConfiguredTransformerFactory() {
    // Used to define the Default XML Transformer to SAXON 9.
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
    return transformerFactory;
}
```

Please if any have a solution to make the `URIResolver.resolve()` be called for EACH `document()` function of XSL or a new way to merge a multiple string-xml to one used to transformation I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using all three of the variables somewhere in the stylesheet? It should work as long as they're accessed. (Creating the variable isn't enough.)

For example, I included the following in my Java:

```
StringURIResolver resolver = new StringURIResolver() {{
    put("doc1", "<test1/>");
    put("doc2", "<test2/>");
}};
```

And the following in my stylesheet (only `$doc1` is used):

```
<xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document('doc1')" />
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document('doc2')" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat('c=', count($doc1/*))"/>
```

Output:

```
RESOLVE WAS CALLED
c=1
```

However, when I include a reference to both:

```
<xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document('doc1')" />
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="document('doc2')" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat('c1=', count($doc1/*))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('c2=', count($doc2/*))"/>
```

It works as expected:

```
RESOLVE WAS CALLED
RESOLVE WAS CALLED
c1=1c2=1
```

Comment: I agree - the only explanation I can think of for the URIResolver not being called is that the variable is never evaluated because it is never referenced.

Comment: Iwburk, many thanks! You're correct. The overtime makes me blind on a single error like this. I make a Junit test and resolves a thousand times and all works now. My error is put a wrong value name on xsl select data. Thanks Michael too.